# List depends on value selection

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have 2 `combobox`. Both `comboBox` value are from `dataset`.

`cb1` contain numeric list `eg : 10, 20, 30`
`cb2` contain numeric list `eg : 10.2, 11.3, 20.5, 24.8, 34.5`

`Cb2` list must be filtered upon cb1 selection

> eg : 10 -> 10.2,11.3    20 -> 20.5, 24.8     30 -> 34.5

How do I code these using vb.net? Im uisng mssql where all the data store in table and visual studio 2005 vb.net

```
cb1 = BilletSize
cb2 = BilletUnitWt
```

**EDIT**:

Code tried so far

```
Private Sub cbBilletSize_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbBilletSize.SelectedIndexChanged 
    Dim SqlStr As String SqlStr = "SELECT tbBilletUnitWt.BilletUnitWtCode FROM tbBilletUnitWt WHERE tbBilletUnitWt.BilletSizeCode = " & Me.cbBilletSize.SelectedValue & ";" 
    Me.cbUnitWt.SelectedValue.RowSource = SqlStr Me.cbUnitWt.SelectedValue.Requery()
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a lot of code you're asking us to write to show you the solution. Are you using EntityFramework at least? Have you tried anything at all so far?

Comment: Im using this stackoverflow for the first time, may i know how to print my code in here as well?

Comment: Done it for you :) For future reference you just need to press edit to edit your question and add code to it.

Comment: Hi Yu, my code is not running as what i want. can you help me with that?

Comment: I'm having a look at the moment, I'll let you know in a bit if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a quick try with lists instead of datasets. Can you see if you can adapt this to make it work for you?

I think you should mostly just have to replace the list operation with the equivalent dataset operation...

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim combobox1Items As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    Dim combobox2Items As List(Of Double) = New List(Of Double)

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        Me.combobox1Items.Add(10)
        Me.combobox1Items.Add(20)
        Me.combobox1Items.Add(30)

        Me.combobox2Items.Add(10.2)
        Me.combobox2Items.Add(11.3)
        Me.combobox2Items.Add(20.5)
        Me.combobox2Items.Add(24.8)
        Me.combobox2Items.Add(34.5)

        With Me.ComboBox1
            .DataSource = Me.combobox1Items
        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim bindingList As New List(Of Double)

        For Each item As Double In Me.combobox2Items
            If item > CInt(Me.ComboBox1.Items(Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)) Then
                Call bindingList.Add(item)
            End If
        Next

        With Me.ComboBox2
            .DataSource = bindingList
        End With

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Im doing the items.add list before this. and it works.
But extracting data from table is more efficient bcuz inside the form when user add a record in Master then i need to add 1 more row of code again instead of running the current code that suits all the condition.
But i really appreciate your help with the code above. Thank you

Comment: OK, sorry if this wasn't any help to you. I unfortunately do not have much experience working with datasets, so I can't offer any more help than this. I hope you can get your code to work.